# nested Dictionary get inner value

Tags: python

I was wondering how to get values depending on "two" keys, when you have a dictionary in a dictionary.
i.e.:

```
street_dict ={"streetA": ["HouseA1", "HouseA2"],
              "streetB": ["HouseB1", "HouseB2"]}

house_dict = {"HouseA1" : ["Jack", "Jones", "Joel"],
              "HouseA2" : ["Paul", "Lucas", "Martin"],
              "HouseB1" : ["Rick", "Jordan", "Michael"],
              "HouseB2" : ["Peter", "George", "Toni"]}
```

- How to find out where Rick lives? (House and Street)
- Whats the fastest way to get all persons of StreetA?

Comment: make dict {person:[street, house}]} and you will get any info without any joining

Comment: If I got you right, you would suggest to make 1 dict out of both right? Could you post the code for doing so? I think yours has a little syntax mistake with the "}" too much.

Comment: Yes - two times :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> - How to find out where Rick lives? (House and Street)

You could use a list comprehension:

```
[(hs,st) for st, j in street_dict.items() for hs in j if 'Rick' in set(house_dict[hs])]
# [('HouseB1', 'streetB')]
```

> - Whats the fastest way to get all persons of StreetA?

Similarly to the above approach:

```
from itertools import chain

list(chain.from_iterable([house_dict[house] for house in street_dict["streetA"]]))
# ['Jack', 'Jones', 'Joel', 'Paul', 'Lucas', 'Martin']
```

Comment: Can you give me a short explanation what ur "j" stands for and why the `set` in `set(house_dict[hs])]` is necessary?

Comment: `j` corresponds to the `values` of the dicts, i.e  the inner lists, hence ` for hs in j` will be retrieving all values in the lsts. And wrt the second point, `sets` are more efficient than lists for checking membership @CRoNiC

Answer (score 1):

You can rebuild you data to a more suitable dictionary

```
hs = {house:street for street,houses in street_dict.items() for house in houses}
s = {person: {'street':hs[house], 'house':house} for house, persons in house_dict.items() for person in persons}
# {'Jack': {'street': 'streetA', 'house': 'HouseA1'}, 'Jones': {'street': 'streetA', 'house': 'HouseA1'},..
```

Then your query will be

```
# where lives Jordan    
print(s['Jordan'])
# all persons of StreetA
print([person for person, address in s.items() if address['street'] == 'streetA'])
```

Answer (score 0):

Find Rick. Not using list comprehension:

```
def find_person(name):
    for house, persons in house_dict.items():
        if name in persons:
            for street, houses in street_dict.items():
                if house in houses:
                    print("{} lives at {} {}".format(name, house, street))
```

Get all persons at a street:

```
def get_persons(street):
    persons = []
    for house in street_dict.get(street, []):
        persons.extend(house_dict.get(house, []))
    return persons
```